# WPF Image Cropping and Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a simple grid that displays a portion of an image.

```
 <Grid x:Name="back_side" Margin="-1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" RenderTransform="{Binding ScaleTransformBack}" Width="Auto">
        <Image Source="/NameSpace;component/Resources/image.jpg" Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding RectGeo}"/>
            </Image.Clip>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

I have tried binding directly to a RectangleGeometry in code behind as well. The clip doesn't seem to want to work. Any suggestions? Anyone have any experience with binding a clip to an image?

I need to be able to programmatically segment a specific image across a number of controls. Using the clip as the calculated portion for each control to display.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to display only part of your image you can use `CroppedBitmap` as `Image.Source`

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="/NameSpace;component/Resources/image.jpg" SourceRect="{Binding RectGeo}"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

You can bind [`CroppedBitmap.SourceRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap.sourcerect(v=vs.110).aspx) but you need to make sure that `RectGeo` is of a [`Int32Rect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.int32rect(v=vs.110).aspx) type

**EDIT**

Unfortunately if you plan to change `SourceRect` at runtime this won't work as:

> After initialization, property changes are ignored

So what you can do is create custom `IValueConverter` which will create a `CroppedBitmap`:

```
public class CropBitmapConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new CroppedBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)parameter, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)), (Int32Rect)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use it with your binding:

```
<Image ... Source="{Binding Path=RectGeo, Converter={StaticResource CropBitmapConverter}, ConverterParameter='pack://application:,,,/NameSpace;component/Resources/image.jpg'}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, using the CroppedBitmap works, however, only if I manually set the RectangleGeometry prior to InitializeComponent();

Comment: It doesn't work when the RectangleGeometry is changed afterwards.

Comment: Do you raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event for `RectGeo` when rectangle dimensions have changed?

Comment: Yes, the UserControl raises notifications.